# RPM conflicts with Python Virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, rpm, rhel

We use a RHEL5 cluster, and we make custom RPM's of our applications so we can deploy them in the field.

I am having an unusual issue where a specific directory within our virtualenv is causing an RPM conflict and I can't figure out why.

We have a package (python26-2.6.5-6.el5.x86_64) that provides our main Python executable. It's installed for other services, but not used by our project. Our project uses a virtualenv.

For some reason the 'encodings' directory of the virtualenv is causing conflicts.

Here is the files provided by the python26 package: https://gist.github.com/reidja/5749089#file-python26-file-list

Here is our spec file: https://gist.github.com/reidja/5749089/raw/8c91a238e488b93d3ca9c4ce07c8eada360095dd/Our+Spec+File

Here is the output from yum:
https://gist.github.com/reidja/5749089/raw/5a543765bfadfb384b6136420527ce941df55bb6/yum+localinstall

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our custom build environment was pulling in symlinks as files (like a cp -H). This was causing the encodings directory in our virtualenv to come in as real files as opposed to symlinking against /usr/lib64